# Ignore ACTION_DOWN on one view but intercept ACTION_UP on a different view

Tags: android, events, view, action, listener

I wasn't able to find a good way to intercept an ACTION_UP on a view other than the one ACTION_DOWN was used on.
This is intended for people with disabilities where the initial point where the screen is touched is *not* their intended target.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to implement onTouchEvent for the whole layout and intercept action_up (that wasn't consumed) from all children like the documentation suggested but it did not work as expected. Ended up setting OnTouchListeners for every button and funneling them to the layout onTouchEvent manually in order to have both children view action_up and the layout action_up events.